# How can I fix my navigation menu bar

Tags: html, css

In my navigation bar, My active button along with my hover button does not align inside with my navigation bar. can someone help me with this?

Here is the link where I am testing this with:

http://jsfiddle.net/3qPbE/63/

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">


.cl{clear:both;}

#navi{
  background:#0082c8;
  position:relative;
  margin-top:0;
  list-style:none;
  height:50px;
}


#navi > li{
float:left;
margin:0 20px;
position:relative;
padding:14px 0;
}

#navi li a, .subnavi li a{
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
line-height:29px;
padding:0 13px;
font-size:16px;
font-family:arial;
text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #034e9f;
filter: dropshadow(color=#034e9f, offx=0, offy=2); 
}

#navi > li:hover > a, #navi li a.active{
background-color:#009;
height:50px;
line-height:29px;
display:block;              
 }

.subnavi{
position:absolute;
display:none;
top:50px;
background:#0082c8;
padding:10px 0;
white-space:nowrap;
list-style:none;    
}

#navi li:hover .subnavi{
display:block;
}

#navi .subnavi li{
margin:0;}

#navi .subnavi li a{
display:block;
font-size:13px;
padding:0 15px;
border-radius:0;
line-height:27px;}


#navi .subnavi li a:hover{
padding:0 15px;
border-radius:0;
border-left:0;
border-right:0;
line-height:25px;}


</style>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
  <ul id="navi">
    <li><a href="" class="active">Home Owners</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Proffesionals</a>
    <ul class="subnavi">
        <li><a href="">LInk 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">LInk 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">LInk 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">LInk 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">LInk 1</a></li>    
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Why Ventilate?</a></li> 
    <div class="cl"></div>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/3qPbE/65/

Change the paddings on `#navi > li` and `#navi li a` and give `#navi > li:hover > a, #navi li a.active` correct height.

```
#navi > li{
    float:left;
    margin:0 20px;
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
}

#navi li a, .subnavi li a{
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    line-height:29px;
    padding:10px 13px;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:arial;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #034e9f;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#034e9f, offx=0, offy=2); 
}

#navi > li:hover > a, #navi li a.active{
    background-color:#009;
    height:30px;
    line-height:29px;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. It has worked. However when I added a div underneath it, it left a small gap in between my navigator bar and my div box where I am going to put a photo rotator. Any reason why this is happening?  Here is a link to a screenshot of what is going on: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9twyb86zs43vsai/web%20screenshot.JPG

Comment: You are welcome. There could be numerous reasons for that gap, the structure of your code, the paddings, margins, positioning and display type... of the elements. You can ask another question and provide the code so we can provide you proper help. However, if my answer solved your current question please mark it as the answer for future reference.

Comment: Thanks man. I am going to try to solve the gap problem on my own. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qPbE/66/)

Remove `height: 50px;` from the navigation `a` tag. That's option 1. Another option would be to increase the height of your `nav` bar. The problem is that by giving the anchor the same height as the nav bar, it's going to be too large following margins and padding.

Your code would look like this:

```
#navi > li:hover > a, #navi li a.active{
    background-color:#009;
    line-height:29px;
    display:block;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the height of your `a:active` element to 29px to match the line height of all other child `a` elements of `#navi`, or just remove it altogether:

```
#navi > li:hover > a, #navi li a.active{
    background-color:#009;
    height:29px;
    line-height:29px;
    display:block;
}
```

I've updated your jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3qPbE/64/

Comment: thanks but i was wondering how do i get the active state and the hover state the same height as the nav bar?  I made the nav bar 50 px but i need the hover and active state to be the same size?